# Simple regular expression when get data from another site

Tags: php, regex

- I want to get a first post content from url to my site . And here is url which i need get :

`http://www.vietvbb.vn/up/forumdisplay.php?f=15`

- So i used firebug to do . And i need get first post content between this html code :

  ```
  <td id="td_post_11229294" class="alt1" style="border-right: 0px solid #262626"><--content that i need--></td>
  ```
- And i did it like this :

  ```
      $url = 'http://www.vietvbb.vn/up/showthread.php?t=65690';
  $data = file_get_contents($url);
  preg_match('/<td class="alt1" id="td_post_(.*?)">\r\n(.*?)\r\n<\/td>/s', $data, $tc);echo '<pre>';print_r($tc);echo '</pre>';
  ```
- But as you see , it not only return that i really need in td tag , **it give me both first content post in td tag and a div tag with id=postmenu_xxx and a table tag with class=tborder (this div and table , they are things i not need )** :

  ```
  <div id="postmenu_11229294_menu" class="vbmenu_popup" style="display:none">.....</div>
  <table class="tborder" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0" align="center" width="100%">....</table>
  ```
- **I only want it return me content between td tag as above . So , how i have to do ?**

Comment: Can you provide a page or content that doesn't contain hardcore porn images? Remember, folks on this site are accessing it from work and we don't want them being tripped up by over protective content filters.

Comment: I added the "php" tag; if I guessed wrong, please remove it and add the correct language tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this for your preg_match:

```
preg_match("/<td id=\"td_post_\d+[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/td>/",$var,$between);
```

It looks for a beginning td tag with id td_post_ plus 1 or more numbers, then matches 1 or more non-closing tag chars, then starts capturing non-opening tag chars.

The above will work for simple cases (it assumes there are no other tags embedded within the td tag).  If you need something more sophisticated, you should probably use a module that can properly parse the DOM, rather than trying to re-invent the wheel.

Edit: it sounds like the content you are trying to parse is not well formed (from your error message) but that shouldn't prevent you from getting what you need.  JQuery, for example, has powerful DOM parsing functions that would let you grab the content within that td tag.

That said, you could always just try a less-specific regex like below, but again, not a substitute for a proper parser:

```
preg_match("/<td id=\"td_post_\d+[^>]+>(.+?)<\/td>/",$var,$between);
```

Comment: Hi , but it return empty array , not array elements . Anyone help me ?

Comment: Post an example of the content you need to grab between the td tag; as mentioned in my post, the above regex will not handle nested tags.  If you need something to handle nested tags, I'd suggest using something to parse the DOM.

Comment: Okay, so you have nested tags.

Comment: Not resolve my problem with DOM , it always give me : Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Opening and ending tag mismatch: tr and center in Entity, line: 533 in D:\xampp\htdocs\lauxanh\class.php on line 45

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Opening and ending tag mismatch: font and strong in Entity, line: 536 in D:\xampp\htdocs\lauxanh\class.php on line 45

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Unexpected end tag : strong in Entity, line: 536 in D:\xampp\htdocs\lauxanh\class.php on line 45